# Adding Dependency to Multiple Modules in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

If I need to use some library in multiple modules and add the line

```
compile 'example.path_to_library'
```

to both modules build.gradle,
will it create only one instance of the library classes and point to that or each module will have 2 separate libraries of the same stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**it will create only one instance of the library classes and point to that.**

The library will be downloaded in your External Libraries folder and both the modules will access the same library.

if it solves your problem..do check this answer as correct..thank you, have a good day :)

Comment: so you are saying that defining a so-called `core` module and add all of the common libraries to it, won't save the final apk size, right?